# Why can't I read from file into buffer?

Tags: c

I have a nonempty file (list.txt) that Im trying to read into a buffer (cache), and then print the buffer to stdout. I've tried the 3 different methods below without success.

```
FILE *list;
char *cache;
long size;

list = fopen("list.txt", "rb"); //open list.txt for reading

if (list==NULL) {
    perror ("Error opening file"); 
    exit(3);
    }

fseek(list, 0, SEEK_END);
if (ftell(list) == 0){
    fprintf(stdout, "list.txt is empty \n");
}

//three different methods - none seem to work. 
while(fgets(cache, sizeof(cache), list)) {}    //method 1
fprintf(stdout, "cache is %s\n", cache);

fgets(cache, sizeof(cache), list);             //method 2
fprintf(stdout, "cache is %s\n", cache);

if (fread(cache, size, 1, list) == 1){         //method 3
    fprintf(stdout, "successful fread: cache = %s\n", cache);
    }
```

My output is as follows:

```
cache is (null)
cache is (null)
```

I promise my file exists and is not empty. How can i get my file contents in that buffer???

Comment: char char* ; is pointer. you not allocating memory for that.SEEK_END will take to you to end of the file. use rewind();

Comment: You're reading into the memory space that `cache` points to; tell me, what does `cache` point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
fseek(list, 0, SEEK_END);
```

puts `list` at the end of the file. You need to rewind the file to be able read its contents.

Add

```
rewind(list);
```

before you read the contents of the file.

**Problem 2**

You also need to allocate memory for `cache` before reading into it.

**Problem 3**

`fgets` reads only one line of text. If you want to read the contents of the entire file, you need to use `fread`.

---

Try:

```
fseek(list, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(list);
if (size == 0)
{
   fprintf(stdout, "list.txt is empty \n");
}

// Rewind the file
rewind(list);

cache = malloc(size+1);
if ( cache == NULL }
{
   // Unable to allocate memory.
   exit(1);
}

int n = fread(cache, 1, size, list);
if ( n != size )
{
   // Was able to read only n characters,
   // not size characters.
   // Print a message.
}

cache[n] = '\0';
fprintf(stdout, "cache is %s\n", cache);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have *not* allocate memory to `char` pointer `cache` . *Allocate memory* to it before using it in `fgets` (*also remember to* `free` *it*).

*Note-* variable `size` in method 3 remains uninitialized , so method 3 has no chance to work .

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't allocate memory for cache. Good idea to use ftell() result.
2. You use "sizeof(cache)". Please note, this is just size of pointer - 4 or 8 bytes.